# Solving the functional equation

Tags: functions

Find all functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x+y)-f(x-y)=4xy$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

I put $x=y=z/2$ and got $f(z)=z^2+C$ for any real constant, but can't prove its the only one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{array}{rcl}
\forall z \in \Bbb R: f \left( \dfrac z2 + \dfrac z2 \right) - f \left( \dfrac z2 - \dfrac z2 \right) &=& 4\left( \dfrac z2\right)^2 \\
f(z) - f(0) &=& z^2 \\
f(z) &=& z^2 + C
\end{array}$

where $C = f(0)$.

Now, to prove that it is consistent:

$\begin{array}{rcl}
\forall x,y \in \Bbb R: f(x+y) - f(x-y) &=& [(x+y)^2 + C] - [(x-y)^2+C] \\
&=& [x^2+2xy+y^2+C]-[x^2-2xy+y^2+C] \\
&=& 4xy
\end{array}$

So, we have proved that $[\forall x,y \in \Bbb R: f(x+y) - f(x-y) = 4xy] \iff [\forall z \in \Bbb R: f(z) = z^2+C]$.

Comment: Simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x+y)-f(x-y)=4xy
$

If $f$ is differentiable,
divide by $2y$ to get
$\frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}=2x
$.

Letting $y \to 0$
gives
$f'(x) = 2x$
so $f(x) = x^2+c$.

This satisfies the equation
for all $c$.

Remove all conditions
on $f(x)$.

Let
$f(x) = x^2+g(x)$.
Then
$4xy
=(x+y)^2+g(x+y)-((x-y)^2+g(x-y))
=4xy+g(x+y)-g(x-y)
$
so
$g(x+y) = g(x-y)
$.

Letting
$x=0$ gives
$g(y) = g(-y)$.

Letting
$x=y$ gives
$g(2x) = g(0)$.

Therefore
$g(x)$ is constant.

Therefore all solutions
are of the form
$f(x)=x^2+c$.

Comment: You can't assume that it is differentiable.

Comment: Sure I can. I did that to find out a class of solutions. I then removed that assumption and derived the general solution.

Comment: Alright, I saw it now. Thank you.

Comment: As I wrote, your solution is more straightforward than mine. I like to show all my steps.