# When are there solutions to $f(x+y)-f(x-y) = axy+bx+cy+d $ and what are they?

Tags: functional-equations

This is a generalization of

[Solving the functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237573/solving-the-functional-equation/2237588#2237588)

When are there solutions to
$f(x+y)-f(x-y)
= axy+bx+cy+d
$
(i.e.,
what restrictions are there on
$a, b, c, d$)
and what are they?

I have a solution,
but want to see
what others come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An immediate observation taking $x=y=0$ is that $d$ must be $0$.

Next, with $y=0$, we find that $0=f(x)-f(x)=bx$ for all $x$, so that $b$ too must be $0$.

At this point, one may repeat DHMO's solution in the linked question to find that solutions do exist and are of the form

$$f(z)=\frac{a}4z^2+\frac{c}{2}z+f(0)$$